# rectangle is not loaded in opengl

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am using visual studio 6 for coding in opengl . Here is my code to build a lamp post .

```
glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex3f(2,2,10);
            glVertex3f(2,6,10);
            glVertex3f(0,10,0);
        }glEnd();

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex3f(10,0,0);
            glVertex3f(8,2,10);
            glVertex3f(2,2,10);
        }glEnd();
        
        glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(2,2,10);
            glVertex3f(2,2,22);
            glVertex3f(2,6,25);
            glVertex3f(2,6,10);
        }glEnd(); 

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(2,2,10);
            glVertex3f(8,2,10);
            glVertex3f(8,2,25);
            glVertex3f(2,2,22);
        }glEnd(); 

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(2,2,10);
            glVertex3f(8,2,10);
            glVertex3f(8,2,25);
            glVertex3f(2,2,22);
        }glEnd(); 

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.27, 0.07);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glVertex3f(2,2,22);
            glVertex3f(8,2,25);
            glVertex3f(8,6,22);
            glVertex3f(2,6,22);
        }glEnd();
```

The output will be as the follows :

[image]

But according to my code is the output should be

[image]

Why ? Is it a visual studio colpiler problem ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Could be either a back side culling problem, or you're trying to draw a concave quad, which is not supported by OpenGL. But seriously, you should not "code" your geometry. Start a program like Blender, create your models there, store them in an easy to read file format and load the geometry data from there.

Answer (score 0):

TThe problem will be solved if the project is cleaned . After that , I have to compile and run the software .